# How to keep a variable alive between all fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

My question is this, I have a fragment where I have a menu and select an option that needs to be applied to each fragment that I have.

For example, in my profile fragment I need to enable a certain team for the user, this team will impact in each fragment since if I select for example United States as a team in my profile fragment, I will need to see information about that team in my other fragments.

My question is, is better to do this with a singleton ? so I make an instance of the selection in my profile and then access this in the other fragments.

Is that a good approach or I need to do this in another way?

Comment: Your best option is to persist the value to Bundle and restore it if the Activity is the first Activity that is opened and savedInstanceState!=null, and put it into a MutableLiveData that is observed with the fragment view lifecycle owner.

Comment: I think SharedPreferences is the best way to persist this data, so it can be retrieved from any fragment or activity

Comment: You've got several options. A few are (1) Keep it in memory as a singleton, (2) store it in the `Activity` containing all your `Fragment`s (assuming they share an Activity), (3) use a persistent storage option (`SharedPreferences`, a file, an `SQLiteDatabase`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be better handled using `shared preferences`. When you select `United States`, just save it against a variable in shared preference which will be available throughout the application.

```
 Button updateTeamName = findViewById(R.id.btnupdateTeamName);
 updateTeamName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("team", "United States");
        editor.commit();
    }
 });
```

When the button `updateTeamName` is clicked, it will put an entry in shared preference, which will be available throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would like to persist such user information like team, name, age, etc.

How you persist the data, which later can be fetched and reused in any other business logic or views, doesn't matter. (Could be e.g. a remote or local database)

I would not recommend to store it to any kind of lifecycle depending Android techniques as you might loose the data when the application gets terminated.

Try to store the data via some kind of persistence layer.
Imho the way you access that persistence layer could be achieved with a singleton object handling access to that layer.

I'll add you various resources to find out which would fit your needs best:

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room
https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices#data-storage
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki#persistence
```

Also check android architecture where you might learn how they handle data over different fragments and views:

```
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a class and for store static variable.

For Example

```
public class S{
 public static int sSocketTimeOutInMS = 50000;
}
```

now u can get this variable everywhere in activities and fragments using ***S.*** 
For example

**`int SocketTimeOut = S.sSocketTimeOutInMS;`**

Comment: Which will not survive process death =)

Comment: as robin says, I dont want users to reselect the team each time they enter into the app, Im going with sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I know for a nowadays app is to use ViewModel from Google Architecture Components. You can share a ViewModel for all fragments and observe the changes from every single fragment using LiveData as someone told you before.